# Remove <div class="something">

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<div class="some class"> some code </div>
```

I have to remove:

```
<div class="some class">
```

Without removing the code inside.

Before:

```
<div class="some class"> some code </div>
```

After:

```
some code
```

I tried using jQuery function `.replaceWith()` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.some-class').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).contents();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class"> some code </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `$(".some.class").unwrap()` should work.

**Edit** : nope it doesn't work, as Karl-André said, there's something missing :

`$(".some.class").contents().unwrap()` works.

Comment: Oops, this actually doesn't work. It unwraps an element from its  _parent_.  PeterKA's answer is the right one. Stop upvoting me and upvote him instead :)

Comment: Okay, keep upvoting me.

Comment: use `$(".some.class").contents().unwrap()` and it work, so yeah, this answer is wrong but close. Just change it.